# Android studio consecutive comments folding

Tags: android-studio, code-folding

I use code regions in Android Studio this way:

[image]

When collapsing all my code, Android Studio used to do this:

[image]

But with the latest update (3.1.1), it now does this:

[image]

Is there a way to revert to the previous behaviour?

EDIT: yes I've been to Preference > Editor > General > Code folding. I unchecked all the boxes, restarted, the problem is still there.